# Undefined index: enviar

Tags: php

Tengo un código para enviar noticias por mail a direcciones que se encuentran almacenadas en una tabla de `MySQL`. A continuación les dejo el código, en donde me da error en la primera línea:

> ($enviar = $_POST['enviar'];)

Que estaré haciendo mal?

```
     <?php

$enviar = $_POST['enviar'];

if (isset ($enviar)) 
{
    $enviar = $_POST['enviar'];
    include ("Connections/conexioncet13.php");
    $resp = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM tblusuario",$conexion);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($resp)) 
    {
        $nombre = $row ["strNombre"];
        $mail = $row ["strEmail"];
        $mensaje = $_POST ["mensaje"];
        $men = "Estimado/a ".$nombre.", \n ".$mensaje."";
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        mail ($mail,"Newsletter de la Supervisión de Nivel Medio",$men,"FROM: glapettina@gmail.com,$headers");
    }
}
else {
?>
    <form action="enviarnews-sup.php" method="post">
      <p>Introduce el Mensaje:</p>
      <p>
      </p>
    <textarea name="mensaje" cols="50" rows="10" class="campo"></textarea>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input name="enviar" type="submit" class="boton" id="enviar" value="Enviar Newsletter"  />
      </p>
    </form>
<?php
}
?>

<?php

$enviar = $_POST['enviar'];

if (isset ($enviar)) 
{
    $enviar = $_POST['enviar'];
    include ("Connections/conexioncet13.php");
    $resp = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM tblusuario",$conexion);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($resp)) 
    {
        $nombre = $row ["strNombre"];
        $mail = $row ["strEmail"];
        $mensaje = $_POST ["mensaje"];
        $men = "Estimado/a ".$nombre.", \n ".$mensaje."";
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        mail ($mail,"Newsletter de la Supervisión de Nivel Medio",$men,"FROM: glapettina@gmail.com,$headers");
    }
}
else {
?>
    <form action="enviarnews-sup.php" method="post">
      <p>Introduce el Mensaje:</p>
      <p>
      </p>
    <textarea name="mensaje" cols="50" rows="10" class="campo"></textarea>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input name="enviar" type="submit" class="boton" id="enviar" value="Enviar Newsletter"  />
      </p>
    </form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Undefined index no es un Error, es un Notice. En este caso te está avisando que $_POST['enviar'] no está definido. Tienes que revisar tu HTML, fíjate bien en el input y que esté dentro del form:

```
<form>
...
<input type="text" name="enviar" value="" />
<button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Quizás te puedo ayudar más si copias el código. ¡Quedo atento!

Answer (score 0):

No tienes que capturas el valor del boton si no el metodo que se esta ejecutando al dar clic en enviar:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') { // si se hizo una solicitud tipo POST
   if(isset($_POST ["mensaje"];)){ // en caso que quieras verificar si la variable mensaje esta definida

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola creo que el detalle esta en que al momento de cargar la página inicializas la variable $enviar, para ello debes de hacer una validación:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["enviar"])){
$enviar = $_POST["enviar"];
}
...
?>
```

Espero te haya servido.